# Restore the Firefox new tab page after being changed by an extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, tabs

A Firefox [extension](https://workona.com/) I have installed has taken control of the new tab page. I want to keep using the extension, but use the original new tab page (`about:newtab`). The extension offers a toggle to "use it on a new tab page", but the toggle does nothing (does not toggle on click) and instead opens [this page](https://workona.com/help/use-other-new-tab-on-firefox/), explaining how the most recently installed extension controls the new tab page.

I have tried installing the extensions [New Tab Override](https://addons.mozilla.org/cs/firefox/addon/new-tab-override/) and [New Tab Homepage](https://addons.mozilla.org/cs/firefox/addon/new-tab-homepage/), but both failed when I entered `about:newtab` as an URL. (First one crashed the browser, second one loaded a white page.)

I have found the value `browser.newtab.extensionControlled = true` in `about:config`, but setting it to `false` or deleting it has no effect and it is reset back to `true` when opening `about:config` the next time.

How do I keep using the original `about:newtab` without removing the extension?

Comment: File a bug report with the authors of the extension.

Comment: @DavidPostill I did, didn't get a response yet. I am asking because I still expect it to be possible to just choose my new tab page manually...

Comment: If the extension keeps setting `browser.newtab.extensionControlled = true` then it's not possible.